# Citation request: we can skip 5 (mod 6) numbers while searching for a counter example of the Collatz Conjecture

Tags: reference-request, collatz-conjecture

I am having trouble finding articles that mention seeds equivalent to 5 (mod 6) are irrelevant when using a program that starts with n = 3 up to some limit. If anyone knows about any articles that mention this, can they link those to me please?

I study the Collatz Conjecture as an amateur, and I stumbled upon this detail I thought could be useful for calculating trajectories. I believe the detail is too obvious for me to be the first person to stumble upon this. After doing some research, I could not find any academic papers or even blog posts that mentioned this. I suspect lots of people already know about this and I looked in the wrong places.

Comment: There are the classical surviving sequences (https://oeis.org/A100982) which are numbers modulo $2^k$, and some known optimizations (http://www.ericr.nl/wondrous/techpage.html) like 2, 4, 5 or 8 mod 9 (6n+5 would be covered by this) which I think came from Oliveira (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220577131_Maximum_excursion_and_stopping_time_record-holders_for_the_problem_Computational_results): 3n+2, 9n+4

Comment: @Collag3n That is interesting, thank you for hunting that down.